# "Timestamp evaluation: connection error" in `DATE_ADD` in `TABLE_DATE_RANGE` in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

When running the following query

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE([ds.table_prefix_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -3, 'MONTHS'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))
```

I receive the following error:

```
Timestamp evaluation: connection error.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a `SELECT` on just the `DATE_ADD` statements, you get a sensible error.

```
Error: Invalid interval unit in function DATE_ADD: MONTHS, expected YEAR, QUARTER, MONTH, WEEK, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE or SECOND.
```

Comment: Nice catch.  Filed as a BigQuery bug, https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=455